# Store images in firebase storage and data in firestore

Tags: html, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 + Firestore(cloud firestore, not realtime database)

I want to select an image through input element and then upload it into firestore storage. All the other data will be stored in cloud firestore.

How do I store image in storage and it's url in firestore?

component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="emailA" #emailA="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.emailA" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="imgurls" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01" >Choose file</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p style="color: red;" *ngIf="form.invalid && form.touched"> *All the fields are required </p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

and this is my component.ts

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

    let data = Object.assign({}, form.value);
    delete data.id;

    if (form.value.id == null) {

      this.firestore.collection('lecturers').add(data);
    }
    else {
      this.firestore.doc('lecturers/' + form.value.id).update(data);
    }
    this.resetForm(form);
    this.toastr.success('Lecturer saved successfully!', 'Lecturer Details');


  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload a file, do the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  uploadFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const filePath = 'name-your-file-path-here';
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
  }
}
```

To get the url:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<img [src]="profileUrl | async" />`
})
export class AppComponent {
  profileUrl: Observable<string | null>;
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
     const ref = this.storage.ref('users/davideast.jpg');
     this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

Then you can store the `url` in firestore.

Check the docs:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md